# Typescript: Merge two types/interfaces and keep all generics valid

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to merge two types and also keep the generics valid.
for example

Type 1

```js
interface Request<P extends core.Params = core.ParamsDictionary, ResBody = any, ReqBody = any, ReqQuery = core.Query> extends core.Request<P, ResBody, ReqBody, ReqQuery> { }
```

Type 2

```js
type Auth = {
  user: User
}
```

I want my new type to be a merge of these two, where the type can receive all those generics.

Right now I am just merging them, but then I am not able to use generics of the `Request` type.

Currently I am just merging these two.

```js
export type Merge<FirstType, SecondType> = Omit<FirstType, keyof SecondType> & SecondType;
```

Of course I can do all this manually, but this case is repeating in my project, I want a utility method which can do this for me.
For example

```js
MergeWithGenerics<Request, Body>
```

Where the new type keeps all generics of the first arg.

I don't know if its possible or not, but it would be really great if someone can help me with this.

Comment: is the goal here to not have to repeat the default types for your generics?

Comment: I'm sorry, pretty sure this is not possibile in TS right now. The best thing you can do `
type MergedGen<P, TRes, TReq, TQuery> = Merge<MyRequest<P, TRes, TReq, TQuery>, Auth>;`, but this is clearly manual

Comment: please make your question more concrete, preferably with a typescript playground link

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass a generic type (without parameters) to another generic type.

```js
interface Generic<P> { }
type Id<T> = T
type G = Id<Generic>; // Generic type 'Generic<P>' requires 1 type argument(s).(2314)
```

That being said, your definition of `Merge` seems to be a pretty good shorthand for what you're trying to do. `Merge<Request<Params, ResBody, ReqBody, Query> & Auth>` doesn't seems a lot bigger then `RequestWithAuth<Params, ResBody, ReqBody, Query>`.

A variation of the proposal from @leonardfactory, might also simplify a bit:

```
 type ExtendedRequest<Extension, P, TRes, TReq, TQuery> = Merge<Request<P, TRes, TReq, TQuery>, Extension>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use a snippet - assuming you're using VSCode or similar.

With following VSCode snippet, you can type "mgen" and tab complete (`ctrl`+`space`), then `tab` on the snippet name. Each time you  push `tab`, cursor will iterate to next variable positions.

snippets.json

```
{

"Merged Generic": {
    "prefix": "mgen",
    "body": [
        "export type Merge<$1, $2> = Omit<$1, keyof $2> & $2;",
    ],
    "description": "shorthand for defining merged generics"
}
```

}
[image]

In your case you probably want 3 or 4 variables.